# Why does the Attribute Sample Texture have 4 columns in the resulting attribute?

Tags: node-editor, geometry

[image]

In the "height" attribute, why is there a column with only zeros? What does it represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's RGBA. The last value is *Alpha* for transparency. Use a transparent image and you will see values greater than zero<sup>1</sup>.

[image: screenshot test scene]
(Note: I had to unwrap the plane again because the default UVMap of the default plane gives me weird values)

RGBA image for testing: [image: test image]

In the settings for the texture, there is a checkbox to invert the Alpha channel if you select an image file as the source (*Texture Properties > Image > Alpha > Invert*).

---

<sup>1</sup> *if it's not fully transparent at the sampled point, of course.*

Comment: ahh, sorry but doesn't an alpha value of 0 mean completely transparent? So shouldn't the values be all 1's?

Comment: I think that's a limitation with color values that will be fixed in the next version

Comment: Looks like the built-in textures (cloud, etc) have a default alpha value of 0. For RGB images it's 1 and for RGBA images it's what the Alpha channel dictates.